# Count a string in a text file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner in Python. I am trying to count a specific character in a text file (a string). I manage to read in the file and with a for loop I try to loop through each row in the text file and find a specific character. The goal is to print out the count of that character. Unfortunately I get 0 as a result although I have a couple of that character in the file.

```
in_file= open("file_x.txt")
lines = in_file.readlines()

d=0

for line in in_file:
    if d in line:
        d=d+1
print(d)
```

Any suggestion? Thank you

Comment: `if d in line:` here `d` is your int variable you have declared above. use `'d'`.

Comment: Also, your loop should loop over the lines, not over `in_file`.

Comment: `for line in in_file:   d+=line.count('d')`

Comment: If a character that you are counting can appear more than once on the same row, you way of counting will miss it.

Comment: or `for line in in_file:   for i in line:    if i=='d':    d+=1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple problems.

First, when reading a file you should specify the mode (not strictly needed, but greeatly helps clarify intent). In this case for reading do:

```
open("file_x.txt", "r")
```

Next, when reading a file you need to make sure you close it after you're done. You should use `with` for this:

```
with open("file_x.txt", "r") as in_file:
    lines = in_file.readlines()
```

You didn't loop the lines, you looped the already read file `in_file`. Change to:

```
for line in lines:
```

You didn't use a string to check the line, you used the variable `d` which is an int `0`. Change to `"d"`

```
if "d" in line:
```

All together now:

```
with open("file_x.txt", "r") as in_file:
    lines = in_file.readlines()

d = 0

for line in lines:
    if "d" in line:
        d += 1

print(d)
```

Another error. If you want to count all occurrences and not just how many lines contain the letter, you'll want to use `str.count`. Also you can avoid calling readline if you directly loop over the file:

```
d = 0
with open("file_x.txt", "r") as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        d += line.count("d")

print(d)
```

Going a bit further with `sum` and a generator expression:

```
with open("file_x.txt", "r") as in_file:
    d = sum(line.count("d") for line in in_file)

print(d)
```

Comment: Is it really an error to use the default mode? If so, why does the default even exist?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode I guess it's not an error, but I can't tell you how many bugs I've seen because people forget that one. To each their own.

Comment: Thank you. Can I use the generator expressions if I have more characters to search? If I have a,b,c,d for example and I want to count all of them

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a separate variable to count the number of occurrences and loop over `lines` instead of `in_file`. 
I've added another loop to count the exact number of occurrences within each line as `if 'd' in line` will not include the total count if the number of occurrences in a line exceeds 1.

```
in_file= open("file_x.txt")
lines = in_file.readlines()

count = 0
key = 'd'

for line in lines:
    for j in line:
        if j == key:
            count+=1

print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you care about the efficency I would suggest generate each line inside a generator function.

```py
def gen_lines():
    with open("file_x.txt", "r") as in_file:
        for line in in_file:
            yield line
```

And than you could calculate it using list comperhension in just one line.

```py
elements = sum[line.count("d") for line in gen_lines()]
```

Comment: I find opening files inside a generator risky as the consumer of the generator object is not guaranteed to reach the `StopIteration` exception which would close your file handle. Consider the example `any(gen_lines())`. This will stop at the first line and not close the file. You should open the file outside the method and pass it to `gen_lines`. Although `in_file` by itself is already iterable by lines, so there's no need.

Comment: Also if you did want to do this, more concisely you can use `yield from` and write `yield from in_file`